# Enforcing complicated constraint in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, data-modeling

Let's say I have three entities:

- Projects
- Sections
- Activities

I wonder if it is possible to enforce the following constraints in my data model:

- A project contains zero or more sections
- A section belongs to one project
- A section contains zero or more activities
- An activity belongs to one project or a section within that project

What is the best way to model those constraints, especially the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Those are relationship between the entities. You should create a `FOREIGN KEY` between the tables to depict that relationship or cardinality.

Like, `Section` table should have a FK referencing to `Project` table since there is `1 .. *` relationship between those tables.

Comment: Let's say I have an activity that belongs to project X, and two sections of which one belongs to project X and the other belongs to project Y. How can I enforce the constraint that the activity may not belong to a section that belongs to project Y?